# Lazy Loading Feature Modules Organisation?

Tags: angular

I have a core Application Shell. I also have several dozen games. Everyone has heard of Monopoly so I will just say that one of my games is that.

It seems from documentation online. Lazy Loading is what I need, because I want to load in Monopoly only if it is required. But in the projects I find online, everything appears to be a single global project.  Where a single repository contains all of the Feature Modules.

As someone with dozens of Games, this isn't great. I am going to end up with a MonoRepo where bugs about Monopoly which is a complex game in itself, end up mashed up with Application Shell bugs.

To put it clearly. I am thinking I want this:

- `github/me/app-shell`
- `github/me/module-monopoly`

I have no idea how to develop `module-monopoly` however. If `app-shell` is my PlayStation and `module-monopoly` is my disk. I still need to put my disc inside a PlayStation to develop it and this is where things get a little hairy.

Are there any resources I can read about this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: actually you want know about how to achieve lazy loading?

Comment: Yes but extracting monopoly into a completely separate project muddies the water. I feel like, in order to develop monopoly, it has to be standalone and run by itself which means it needs to have an index.html and essentially be its own Angular Project, but I want to consume only a module from that for production. I just am unclear on the standard way to achieve this.